# Query Facebook for all pages owned by a given Application ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have inserted the following meta tag into 600+ web pages:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID" />
```

How can I query Facebook for a result set of all pages that are administered by this AppID?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to query one of the FQL tables for that information. Probably the domain_admin or page_admin table.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/domain_admin
or
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin